# How to hide shadows in UITableViewCell when cell is dragging

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have UITableView with hided separator line, and when I dragging cell, shadows appears some kind as borders comes out on up and down. How to hide this? Please see example:
[image: Emulator screenshot]

Great thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I have answer, just subclass of UITableView with method:

```
- (void) didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    [super didAddSubview:subview];

    if([subview.class.description isEqualToString:@"UIShadowView"]) {
        subview.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about ios 7? Solution with UIShadowView hide doesn't work.

Comment: yeap, and I again in search for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

NoShadowTableView.m

```
#import "NoShadowTableView.h"

@interface NoShadowTableView ()
{
    //  iOS7
    __weak UIView* wrapperView;
}

@end

@implementation NoShadowTableView

- (void) didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    [super didAddSubview:subview];

    //  iOS7
    if(wrapperView == nil && [[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"])
        wrapperView = subview;

    //  iOS6
    if([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIShadowView"])
        [subview setHidden:YES];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //  iOS7
    for(UIView* subview in wrapperView.subviews)
    {
        if([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIShadowView"])
            [subview setHidden:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack is subclassing UITableViewCell and add method:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        superview?.subviews.filter({ "\(type(of: $0))" == "UIShadowView" }).forEach { (sv: UIView) in
            sv.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me!

```
import UIKit

class NoShadowTableView: UITableView {

    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.didAddSubview(subview)
        if "\(type(of: subview))" == "UIShadowView" {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem by using default UITableView reordering controls. So I used this external third-party library which solved my problem.

https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 implementation (removed iOS6 support)

```
import UIKit

class NoShadowTableView: UITableView {

    weak var wrapperView: UIView?

    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.didAddSubview(subview)

        if wrapperView == nil && "\(type(of: subview))" == "UITableViewWrapperView" {
            wrapperView = subview
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        wrapperView?.subviews.forEach({ view in
            if "\(type(of: view))" == "UIShadowView" {
                view.isHidden = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me hacks with the UIShadowView didn't work. I checked the solution on iOS 10. But one line in a **cell** class has done the trick:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.subviews.filter{ $0 is UIImageView }.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 solution; use extended uitableviewcontroller because now shadow is in the table and only added when cell is moved.

```
class UITableViewControllerEx: UITableViewController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        view.subviews.filter({ String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UIShadowView" }).forEach { (sv: UIView) in
            sv.isHidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers appear to be using private APIs which is obviously not a good thing to do. Additionally, they don't appear to work anymore (at least not on iOS 16).

I found that using `UIDragPreviewParameters` allowed me to get rid of the horrible background colour and reshape the shadow to fit one of the subviews in my table view cell.

```
-(UIDragPreviewParameters *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView dragPreviewParametersForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self createParametersForTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(UIDragPreviewParameters *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView dropPreviewParametersForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self createParametersForTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(UIDragPreviewParameters *)createParametersForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    // Get the selected table view cell.
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Create the dragged cell preview parameters.
    UIDragPreviewParameters *parameters = [[UIDragPreviewParameters alloc] init];
    [parameters setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [parameters setVisiblePath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.customSubView.frame cornerRadius:22.2]];
    [parameters setShadowPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.customSubView.frame cornerRadius:22.2]];
    
    return parameters;
}
```

If you use this method, you will need to implement two delegates: `UITableViewDragDelegate` and `UITableViewDropDelegate`.

```
[yourTableView setDragDelegate:self];
[yourTableView setDropDelegate:self];
```

The drag delegate method will allow you to control the preview background when dragging the cell. When dropping the cell, you need to use the drop delegate method to avoid the preview background going back to the default white background.