# Remove shadow of the UIDragPreview while item dragging

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView based component, when user dragging some cells, shadows appears and I want to hide it.

[image]

I tried many solutions like this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046863/1705700
but no result. Here is my code;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let item = self.itemList[indexPath.row]
        var dragItem: UIDragItem!
        if let path = item.icon {
            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: path as NSString)
            dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
            dragItem.localObject = item
            
            dragItem.previewProvider  = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
                let previewImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test"))
                previewImageView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
                
                let dragPreview = UIDragPreview(view: previewImageView)
                return dragPreview
            }
        }
        
        return [dragItem]
    }
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
        let previewParameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()
        previewParameters.backgroundColor = .clear
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            previewParameters.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: .zero)
        }
                
        return previewParameters
    }
```

I solved the problem. If I use UIDragPreviewParameters as a parameter of UIDragPreview, background and shadow are disappear.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let mood = self.moodList[indexPath.row]
        var dragItem: UIDragItem!
        if let path = mood.icon {
            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: path as NSString)
            dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
            dragItem.localObject = mood
            
            guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {return [dragItem]}
            let cellInsetContents = cell.contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
            
            dragItem.previewProvider  = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
                let previewImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test"))
                previewImageView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
                
                let dragPreviewParams = UIDragPreviewParameters()
                dragPreviewParams.backgroundColor = .clear
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    dragPreviewParams.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: .zero)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }

                dragPreviewParams.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90), cornerRadius: 0)
                
                let dragPreview = UIDragPreview(view: previewImageView, parameters: dragPreviewParams)
                return dragPreview
            }
        }
        
        return [dragItem]
    }
```